# How can i read data from a web service?

Tags: php, web-services

i want use some data from a website with web service.
i have a username & password and i dont know how can i use webservice

Comment: There are many types of web service, you'll need to provide some actual information about it, such as a link to it if it's a public service. As a wild stab in the dark (assuming it's a SOAP service) I would say you probably want to read up on PHP's SoapClient.

Comment: A little more information about the service would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to start is with their API documentation. This will determine the following:

- the url to request information
- the variables to be passed
- how the information is returned

Once you have that information you will need to set up a script to request the information. This is typically accomplished using CURL or through a socket request. Once you get the data data back, you will be able to parse through it (SOAP, JSON, XML, CSV, etc).

If you post the webservice you are using, we can be of more help. But not knowing what you are using, this will be as much information as anyone can provide.